# Why the tangent bundle of a smooth manifold is an oriented manifold?

Tags: differential-topology

I need help with the following question.  I am not sure how to begin.  Any help will be appreciated.  Thank you!

For any smooth manifold $M,$ the tangent bundle $TM$ is an oriented manifold.

Comment: Are you comfortable with the fact that it's a manifold?

Comment: I know what a manifold is.  I'm not confortable with oriented things I guess.

Comment: I think what Sammy means is: Are you familiar with _how_ $TM$ is a manifold.  That is, do you know what the usual charts are on $TM$?  You'll need this in order to work through Alex Youcis' hint.

Comment: Also, could you perhaps change the title to make it more specific to the question, perhaps involving the words "tangent bundle" and "oriented"?  Because the differential-topology tag already tells us the subject matter, there's no need to repeat it in the title.  Thank you!

Comment: This sound more like a topic in differential manifolds, not differential topology. The later subject is primarily surgery theory on high dimensional manifolds.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Take an atlas on $M$, say $\{(U,\varphi)\}$ and look at the corresponding atlas on $TM$, $\displaystyle \left(U,\frac{\partial}{\partial \varphi}\right)$. What is the determinant of these overlap maps' Jacobians?